renovation at office building causing concern
I'm in the US, working for a large employer. We have a huge office building that opened in 1995 but recently they started doing renovations in one part of it. I'm worried about asbestos exposure, but I don't know exactly what they are doing, as the area is sealed off with plastic, but there are drilling and hammering sound. There is a lot of employees in the building.
How worried should I be? The employer does seem to have a culture of following rules and regulation. I wonder what kind of regulations are there when it comes to protecting workers, and how common is this?

Did you ask your employer?

In 1995 asbestos was illegal. It's been banned since 1989. Have you been notified of asbestos in the building?  The process to remove asbestos, for those that are removing it, is fairly involved.  Since it was illegal when the building was built the chances asbestos is contained within the building is less than 0%. It's perfectly normal to seal of a construction area in a building full of people.

If none of the workers is sunning around in full haz mat gear, there is no asbestos.

asbestos mitigation requires isolation the area multiple times, so the section being mitigated, is entirely isolated from the rest of the building. Plastic by itself isn’t enough. You also have to have negative pressure. As others also point out. You also have to wear special protective clothing.

@Donald, I thought the US only recently banned asbestos? Are there regulations in the US when it comes to doing renovation on office buildings that "might" have asbestos? Do they do asbestos surveys prior to renovation?

@user173729 - It’s been banned for 30 years (1989) from construction.  asbestos remediation is expensive, complicated, and specific regulations must be followed to remove it. I encourage you to do research on the subject. You could just your employer. They are legally obliged to inform you about the existence of asbestos.

1995 is new enough it shouldn't be a concern.  Most uses were banned in the '70s, with odds and ends cleaned up in 89/90.
https://www.epa.gov/asbestos/epa-actions-protect-public-exposure-asbestos#:~:text=Learn%20more%20about%20the%201989,conduits%20unless%20certain%20conditions%20specified.

And, sealing the area off with plastic could be for dust mitigation or something similarly innocuous.
